# Pushsharp support of Apple Push Notification Authentication Key

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

Does [pushsharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp) supports a new [Apple approach](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/724) for sending APN using **Apple Push Notification Authentication Key** (which never expires) instead of using Certificates? Is any way to use it with pushsharp? If not, is there any other C# library to support it?

Comment: Hi, may I know if you have found the answer to this? Thanks.

Comment: No. I think nothing is supported so far. I just keep using the old code and certificates for now. Hope they will add this capability in the future

Answer (score 1):

here you are:

```
private string GetToken()
{
    var algorithm = "ES256";
    var teamID = "teamID";
    var apnsKeyID = "apnsKeyID";
    var apnsAuthKeyPath = @"apnsAuthKeyPath";
    var epochNow = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();

    var header = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "alg", algorithm },
        { "kid" , apnsKeyID }
    };
    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "iss", teamID },
        { "iat", epochNow }
    };

    var privateKey = GetPrivateKey(apnsAuthKeyPath);
    var token = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, privateKey, algorithm: Jose.JwsAlgorithm.ES256, extraHeaders: header);
    return token;
}
private CngKey GetPrivateKey(string apnsAuthKey)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(apnsAuthKey))
    {
        var ecPrivateKeyParameters = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
        var x = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineXCoord.GetEncoded();
        var y = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineYCoord.GetEncoded();
        var d = ecPrivateKeyParameters.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
        return EccKey.New(x, y, d);
    }
}
```

then you can simply call send method in apns.